# Bourbon/Neat: Reset margin and let nested divs span the whole width

Tags: grid, sass, css-frameworks, bourbon, neat

I am new to Bourbon/Neat. I have a question concerning nesting: I want the red boxes fill the whole width, without a gutter between them. When using "@include omega" on them, the first box removes its margin-right, but the right box has still the margin and doesn't adjust its width.

Can u tell me how I can make them span the whole parent box without any margin between them?

Here's a demo: http://wuergeengel.net.dd13736.kasserver.com/

**Here's my markup:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-left"></div>
  <div class="box box-right">
    <div class="box-red-left nested"></div>
    <div class="box-red-right nested"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here are my styles:**

```
.container
{
  @include outer-container;
}

.box
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
}

.box-left
{
  @extend .box;
  @include span-columns(4);
}

.box-right
{
  @extend .box;
  @include span-columns(8);

  .nested
  {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 400px;


    &.box-red-left
    {
      @extend .nested;
      @include span-columns(3 of 8);
      @include omega;
    }

    &.box-red-right
    {
      @extend .nested;
      @include span-columns(5 of 8);
      @include omega;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple ways that you can do this.

- Use Neat's table display layout. eg: `@include span-columns(5 of 8, table);`
- Use Neat's underlying `flex-grid` and `flex-gutter` functions. eg:

  ```
  width: flex-grid(5, 8) + flex-gutter(8);
  float: left;
  ```

Answer (score 18):

Or this:

> ```
> @include span-columns(5 of 8, block-collapse)
> ```

See:
http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/#span-columns